# Laravel - Recomended authentication for a REST api

Tags: php, rest, ember.js

I'm building a RESTful api using Laravel that is serving an Ember js application.

I'm currently trying to implement [oath-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) but I'm not sure it will work for my proposes(to serve my js application).

I don't want to use ssl because of the overhead and basic authentication won't suffice. Tried to take a look at HTTP Digest but apparently it's not that safe.

This is my first time building a serious RESTful api and I'm a bit lost when it comes to this. So I'm looking for advice, maybe there's a better package for it or I will have to develop my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It strongly depends who should be able to authenticate against your API. If you just want to access the API from your own js-client, an OAuth implementation is imho a huge overhead.

If basic auth / auth digest is too weak for your case, you can have a look at the concept of [hmac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). There are also a few [packages](https://packagist.org/search/?q=hmac) available which should it make easy to integrate it in L4.

But just in case, OAuth is a great choice if you're planing to grant API access to 3rd-party clients/developers. I'd recommend you the [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) which is a laravel4 integration of [the phpleague oauth2 server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server). I just finished a project with this package, worked out very nice.

Just my 2 cents, hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reponse, I decided to go phpleague oath2 as the api will be somewhat public.